# How do I save a webpage state to mongodb without spamming http requests?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have a to-do list that works like trello, with lists and draggable cards. I have the app functioning with both saving the state of the cards to mongoDB and localstorage using JSON. What I don't understand is how I am supposed to be constantly updating mongoDB every time I move or edit a card. It seems there must be a different way. Just for reference - this is the function I am using to update the DB entry. It saves and renders, but it feels wrong to be doing this with each state change.

```
async function mainUpdate(data) {
  const uri =
    'mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/test';

  const client = new MongoClient(uri);

  try {
    await client.connect();
    await updateListingByName(client, 'user-jeff', { cachedState: data });
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: By state change do you mean in the middle of the drag or when the user finally drops the card?

Comment: When the user drops the card. I have it saving properly only on the end of the drag, but it just feels like I'm doing something wrong by updating the DB on every change.....or is that correct? (Clearly a beginner)

Comment: Then that's normal. It is the standard thing to do. Your feeling of "wrongness" is only your personal feeling and is not shared by other programmers in the industry. You could reduce load by saving most states to localstorage or a caching system (redis, memcache etc.) and periodically sync with your database but that is a fairly advanced thing to do and is not the standard way to solve the problem. People only do such things when they have scaling issues maybe 3 or 5 years after product has launched and the project has around 10 to 50 developers working on it

Comment: Note that one of the backend caching technology commonly used to solve scaling issue is to save the data on Mongodb before syncing to the slower database like MySQL or Oracle but you are already using Mongodb

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm on the right path then. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also note that typically your database has much higher capacity and throughput than your HTTP server so when you hit scaling issues your first optimization is probably to make your web server faster or to load balance your web server. It takes a long time and a lot of clients using the system before you need to update your database architecture.